# JSON Data are not Properly Displayed in the MP Android Chart?

Tags: android, json, mpandroidchart

I am able to Parse the JSON Data and Display the information in the LOG but the Data are not Properly Displayed in the Graph.I have Added Labels to be Displayed but unfortunately the Labels are not Displayed too.

**Dashboard**

```
public class Dashboard extends Fragment {

    ListView listViewNotice, listviewpendingbills;
    String Navigation_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/academics/getNotices";
    String Navigation_URL_BIlls = "http://192.168.100.5:84/Api/financeApi/getAllFees";
    String Navigation_URL_CHART = "http://192.168.100.5:84/api/academics/getSingleStudentsMarks";

    String access_token;
    String Notice, BillNumber, Status, AmountPaid, ReceiptIssueDate;
    String master_id;
    TextView pendingbills, NoNotice;
    BarChart lineChart;


    LineChart chart;


    private static final String TAG = "Test";
    ArrayList<Entry> entries;
    ArrayList<String> labels;
    LineDataSet set;
    LineData data;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        // getActivity().setTitle("St. Xavier's High School");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        listViewNotice = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_student_notice_dashboard);
        listviewpendingbills = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_dashboard_pendingbills);
        pendingbills = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textpendingbills);
        NoNotice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textnoticedashboard);
        //  lineChart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart1);
        chart = (LineChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart1);


        SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(getContext());
        session.checkLogin();
        access_token = session.getAccesstToken();
        master_id = session.getMasterId();
        makeJsonObjectRequest();
        makeJsonObjectRequestBills();
        makeJsonObjectRequestGraph();


        entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        //  set = new LineDataSet(entries, "Valuesl");
        //  data = new LineData(set);


        entries.add(new Entry(0f, 30f));
        entries.add(new Entry(1f, 80f));
        entries.add(new Entry(2f, 36f));
        entries.add(new Entry(3f, 40f));
        entries.add(new Entry(23.00f, 0));
        entries.add(new Entry(40.00f, 1));
//       entries.add(new Entry(00.00f, 2)); // want to skip this index 2(Mar)
//       entries.add(new Entry(00.00f, 3)); // want to skip this index 3 (Apr)
        entries.add(new Entry(94.00f, 4));
        entries.add(new Entry(20.00f, 5));


        // entries.add(new Entry(4f, 0));
        //entries.add(new Entry(8f, 1));
        //entries.add(new Entry(6f, 2));
        //entries.add(new Entry(2f, 3));
        //entries.add(new Entry(18f, 4));
        //entries.add(new Entry(9f, 5));


        // chart.invalidate();

        labels = new ArrayList<>();
        labels = new ArrayList<>();
        labels.add("Nepali");
        labels.add("English");
        labels.add("Math");
        labels.add("Science");

        //  Collections.sort(entries, new EntryXComparator());


        return view;
    }

      private void makeJsonObjectRequestGraph() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL1 = Navigation_URL_CHART + "?StdID=" + master_id;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL1,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String Marks = jsonObject.getString("Marks");
                                String examDescription = jsonObject.getString("examDescription");


                                if (examDescription.equals("First Term")) {
                                    entries.add(new BarEntry(Float.parseFloat(Marks), i));
                                    System.out.println(new BarEntry(Float.parseFloat(Marks), i));
                                    // chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));


                                }


                            }

                            set = new LineDataSet(entries, "");
                            data = new LineData(set);
                            chart.setData(data);

                            chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            chart.invalidate();
                            set.setColor(Color.RED);


                            Collections.sort(entries, new EntryXComparator());


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }
/*
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("id", master_id);
                map.put("accessID", accessID);
                map.put("currentUser", master_id);
                return map;

            } */
        };


        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }


    }
```

**Log output**

```
05-21 16:50:43.405 12459-12459/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: Entry, x: 80.0 y: 0.0
05-21 16:50:43.405 12459-12459/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: Entry, x: 80.0 y: 1.0
05-21 16:50:43.405 12459-12459/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: Entry, x: 80.0 y: 2.0
05-21 16:50:43.405 12459-12459/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: Entry, x: 80.0 y: 3.0
05-21 16:50:43.405 12459-12459/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: Entry, x: 80.0 y: 4.0
05-21 16:50:43.491 12459-12459/com.example.user.mis W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

> How can the information be displayed properly in Graph ?

Comment: Perhaps try and reduce the problem to a [mcve]. There are two subtasks in your question, parsing the JSON and displaying the JSON on the chart. First try and perform the parsing successfully. For that, you will need to include the JSON you are trying to parse.

Comment: I have parsed it very well and able to Display in the Graph but the information are not setted right.Edited please check

Comment: You're making the entries wrong - the first param in the constructor for Entry is the x-value, the second is the y-value. This should be clear from your logcat where you have 5 entries which are all at x-value 80. You want the "marks" to be the y-values not the x-values

Comment: Also don't sort the entries after you have added them to the chart, that will cause problems. Also you will need to use an `IValueFormatter` to get the labels you want on the chart. Please see the wiki in the github repo

Comment: I am not able to set the value of marks in the Y-axis

Comment: @DavidRawson i am not Able to interchange the X-axis Value and the Y-axis Value.Can you please Help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144802/discussion-between-ghimire-and-david-rawson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the x-axis and Y-axis Values.And the Marks would be plotted as required by yours.

```
 private void makeJsonObjectRequestGraph() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL1 = Navigation_URL_CHART + "?StdID=" + master_id;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL1,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String Marks = jsonObject.getString("Marks");
                                String examDescription = jsonObject.getString("examDescription");


                                if (examDescription.equals("First Term ")) {
                                    entries.add(new BarEntry(i, Float.parseFloat(Marks)));
                                    System.out.println(new BarEntry(i, Float.parseFloat(Marks)));


                                }


                            }

                            set = new LineDataSet(entries, "Wow");

                            data = new LineData(set);
                            chart.setData(data);

                            chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            chart.invalidate();
                            set.setColor(Color.RED);


                            //Collections.sort(entries, new EntryXComparator());


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }
/*
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("id", master_id);
                map.put("accessID", accessID);
                map.put("currentUser", master_id);
                return map;

            } */
        };


        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

change

**entries.add(new BarEntry(Float.parseFloat(Marks), i));**

To

> **entries.add(new BarEntry(i, Float.parseFloat(Marks)));**

**TO display Label**

```
add this
```

chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));

Comment: Do i have to Sort or not?

Comment: just a sec.I am implementing it

Comment: The data are Diplayed in the Graph.But Labels are not Displayed

Comment: @prasadShinde sure mate.That issue has been solved. And i have improved alot in Debugging too :) .Thank you for late reply